# How to make a reminder command with MongoDB? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pymongo

I am actually new to datetime and discord.py and databases.

I want to create a reminder command in my discord.py bot. However I would like to use mongodb as a database, instead of using asyncio, as in case my bot goes offline for some reason, all reminders will be gone.

I do not know where to start and i could not find any youtube tutorials for doing this.

Here is my code:

```
import pymongo
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os


Mongo_url = os.environ['Mongodb_url']


client = pymongo.MongoClient(str(Mongo_url))
```

That is the starter code. I do not know where to go after that.

Answer (score 1):

You could start off by using this [example](https://github.com/PloxHost-LLC/community-bot) as a good example of how to use pymongo with discord.py. Pymongo is fine for smaller bots but you should use something like `motor` instead of the normal pymongo as it supports async/await.

You can setup the database/collection like so:

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient(str(Mongo_url))
database = client.bot
collection = database.reminders
```

Then in your command, you can insert it, you could use tasks to check if the reminder is past its time to be displayed then display it. (Add it to the collection, Use asyncio.sleep if it's under 15 minutes but if longer just let it go to the task)

Use this to add/insert to the collection, stores the guild/server id, creator id and the time it was issued, when it should be done by, the message and the id to help identify the reminder.

```py
collection.insert_one(
                {"guild_id": ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id, "issued": datetime.datetime.now(),"requested_time": "datetime of the time when it's needed", "message": "Reminder message here", "id":"some random id for it, you could use a flake id or the ctx.message.id for this"})
```

Then in your task you would have

```py
for reminder in collection.find({}):
   # Your code here that goes through each reminder in the collection
```

Comment: I do use `Motor`. I have continued this question in another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083093/reminder-command-using-mongodb-discord-py