# Reminder Command using MongoDB discord.py

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.py, tornado-motor

I am new to databases and datetime and stuff.

I actually want to create a reminder command which uses MongoDB as a Database. I am using Motor as I want to use asyncio along with it. Please tell me if I am on the right path or not and if I am not, then what should I do?

I have setup the basic connection with MongoDB using motor.

Here is my code.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os
import asyncio
import motor
import motor.motor_asyncio

class Reminder(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Reminder is Ready.')


    ### MongoDB Variables ###

    @commands.command()
    async def remind(self, ctx, time, *, msg):


        ### MongoDB Variables ###
        mongo_url = os.environ['Mongodb_url']
        cluster = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(str(mongo_url))
        db = cluster['Database']
        collection = db['reminder']

        
        ### Discord Variables ###
        author_id = ctx.author.id
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id


        ### Time Variables ###
        time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}
        remindertime = int(time[0]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]

        if ctx.author.bot:
            return

        if (await collection.count_documents({}) == 0):
            rem_info = {"_id": author_id, "GuildID": guild_id, "time": remindertime, "msg": msg}

            await collection.insert_one(rem_info)
            await ctx.send('Logged In')

        


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Reminder(bot))
```

#### What is Reminder Command and whati want to do?

Basically, the command will take the amount of time to be reminded and the topic to be reminded about as arguments.
After the certain amount of time specified in the command, it will DM the user that "You asked me to remind you about {topic}".

I hope that is all the needed information.

Comment: does the code store the intended data in the db? then you are on the right track  you can do the reaminder with a [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) loop

Comment: Yes the data is stored. However, the data is only stored when there are no documents in my collection. Can i do that whenever that command is executed inside discord, the reminder will be registered in the database?

Comment: its because of this i guess: `if (await collection.count_documents({}) == 0):` just remove it or you can add a filter to it like `count_documents({'_id': author_id})`, also when `_id` is the authors id, every user can only have one reminder at same time

Comment: Can you show me the code for using `@tasks.loop()` with my reminder command(please do not tell me to just see the documentation as i did but i am not sure how to do this stuff).

Comment: Like should my whole command be under `@task.loop()`? I really do not know

Comment: Your command can stay that way, in the task.loop you check the time of the saved reminders and then, if necessary, write the user a dm.

Comment: I do know that. however how do I do that?. Can you just show me the code. I am new to this stuff, that's why I am asking that.

Comment: yea am already writing an answer, give me some minutes :D

Comment: Ok sure thing. Sorry if i am being very hasty.

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I haven't tried it yet. I will try tomorrow. Will tell you after that. It probably will be helpful and your answer will work

Answer (score 0):

attachment to the comments below the question:

to check if it is time to remind a user you can use the `datetime` module

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os
import asyncio
import motor
import motor.motor_asyncio

import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

### MongoDB Variables ###
mongo_url = os.environ['Mongodb_url']
cluster = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(str(mongo_url))
db = cluster['Database']
collection = db['reminder']

class Reminder(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.reminder_task.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.reminder_task.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
    async def reminder_task(self):
        reminders = collection.find({})
        for reminder in reminders:
            # reminder should look like this: {"_id": 1234, "GuildID": 1234, "time": datetime_objekt, "msg": "some text"}
            now = datetime.now()
            if now >= reminder:
                # remind the user 
                guild = self.client.get_guild(reminder['GuildID'])
                member = guild.get_member(reminder['_id'])
                await member.send(f"reminder for {reminder['msg']}")
            



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Reminder is Ready.')


    @commands.command()
    async def remind(self, ctx, time, *, msg):
        """Reminder Command"""
        # like above
        
        # just change this
        ### Time Variables ###
        time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}
        remindseconds = int(time[0]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]
        remindertime = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=remindseconds)


        


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Reminder(bot))
```

Comment: not sure if this `reminders = collection.find({})` works like that with `motor` but i guess you know what i mean with it, just find all documents

Comment: This is not working for some reason. I want to dm the user. I tried using `ctx.author.send('message')`. I did add `ctx` as an argument in `@tasks.loop`.

[Here is the link](https://replit.com/@NishilSheth/Shiny-disc-bot#rem_cmd.py) to my code. Check the file `rem_cmd.py`. You will find the code there.

Comment: I do not get any error in the console, nor do i get any DM. There is no data going into into my database.

Comment: you cant do that on tasks, you have to get the member -  i will edit my answer for that

Comment: I have a question, which is probably not necessary, but just to confirm,

Comment: Do I have to write some code in `#reminder should now look like....` You know, to register in the database.

Comment: no this is just what `reminder` is in the for loop ;) try to `print(reminder)` and you will see :)

Comment: The command still does not work. There is no error in the console and no DM is sent to the author

Comment: As always, you can check the link I sent in the comments above to check my code.